# How to include a data file in a chrome app for a native client module to read

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

If I have a chrome packaged app that also includes a PNaCl/NaCl module, is there a way to include in the packaged app some data files, which the NaCl module will then read in?

I don't need to do any file writing, just to include some data files that the native module needs to make use of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire contents of your packaged app are available to both JavaScript and NaCl code via http requests.

If you use the nacl_io library then you can also access all the files using standard POSIX file APIs by first mounting the contents of the package somewhere if your virtual filesystem:

e.g:

```
// Mount the http root at /mnt/package/
mount("/", "/mnt/package/", "httpfs", 0, "");
FILE* f = fopen("/mnt/package/somefile", "r");
```

Comment: I tried this, and while it is the correct thing to do, I am still unable to access the files. See this new question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619708/cant-get-nacl-c-module-to-load-file-from-within-packaged-app